# Error 3115 on AS3 and sqlite (using static keyword)

Tags: sqlite, actionscript-3

```
package com.cameleoninteractive.data 
{
    import flash.data.SQLConnection;
    import flash.data.SQLSchemaResult;
    import flash.data.SQLStatement;
    import flash.data.SQLMode;
    import flash.data.SQLResult;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.SQLEvent;
    import flash.events.SQLErrorEvent;
    import flash.errors.SQLError;
    import flash.filesystem.File;


    public class DBManager 
    {
        private static var _resultArray:Array;
        private static var _stat:SQLStatement;
        private static var _sqlResult:SQLResult;
        private static var _con:SQLConnection;
        private static var _dbFile:File;
        private static var _schema:SQLSchemaResult;     

        public function DBManager() 
        {

            _dbFile = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("WHG_data/product_data.sqlite");

        }


        //SELECT all entries from entered table
        public static function ReadAll(table:String):void
        {
            try {
                _con = new SQLConnection();
                _con.addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, onOpen);
                _con.addEventListener(SQLEvent.CLOSE, onClose);
                _con.open(_dbFile);
                _con.begin();
                _stat = new SQLStatement();
                _stat.sqlConnection = _con;
                _stat.text = "SELECT * FROM " + table;
                _stat.execute();

                _sqlResult = _stat.getResult();         
                _resultArray = new Array();

                //if _sqlResult != null populate _resultArray with data
                if (_sqlResult.data != null)
                {
                    for (var i:int = 0; i < _sqlResult.data.length; i++) 
                    {
                        var obj:Object = _sqlResult.data[i]; 
                        _resultArray.push(obj);
                    }
                }
            }catch (error:SQLError)
            {
                trace(error.message + "  |  " + error.details);
            }finally
            {
                _con.commit();
                _con.close();
            }
        }



        //getter for _resultArray
        public static function get ResultArray():Array
        {
            return _resultArray;
        }


        //remove listener once connection to database is open
        private static function onOpen(event:SQLEvent):void
        {
            _con.removeEventListener(Event.OPEN, onOpen);
            trace("connection open");
        }

        //remove listener once connection to database is closed
        private static function onClose(event:SQLEvent):void
        {
            _con.removeEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onClose);
            trace("connection closed");
        }

    }

}
```

This is my class for retrieving data from my sqlite database. Pretty simple i guess. Now i m having an error message return saying the entered table does not exist.

-path to database files are correct | tables in database exist and are populated with data-

The same exact class with all the static keywords removed works great. This one does not. I ve recently read an article about the static keyword and from what i gather its the best way to give accessibility to a class from different places without needing to instantiate every time. Now, since i am not an expert on programming and i have been reading things in a language that is not my motherstongue i wonder if i understood something wrong.

Is static the way to go when you need accessibility all over the place? If yes, did i understant something incorrectly about the use of it?
can it be a permissions problem? and if yes how can i fix it?

i would appreciate any direct answer as much as any redirection to a url where i can find comprehensive instructions.

i have searched stackoverflow too and found a similar question to my problem. alas the person there posted only that he has resolved his problem but didnt provide any information on how or where he found the information that helped him.

finally i would appreciate if your answers or your links are as less generic as possible. i am allready enough confused as it is.

thanks in advance 
A.K.

Comment: No, don't abuse `static` this way. You don't have to instantiate your class everywhere. You can pass a reference to those classes that need it.

Comment: Firstly thank you for taking the time to respond. Now, it looks like i have got the whole static concept wrong. Could you provide any links to a decent article and/or tutorial on the subject?